# How can I create a text watermark without an image?

Tags: css

What css is required to create a watermark that displays text based upon the content of the page requested?

I am generating the page content using Drupal. The intent here is to enhance the page graphically with relevant content.  So, in addition to a title and body of the page, I would like to have a couple related key words appear as a translucent background under the page content and over a background image.  Both background images and the watermark text will vary for different categories of information.

Comment: Could you expand on your question? Are you trying to cover up an image to prevent image theft? Are you trying to make a document look like it's been marked as a draft? What do you want the output to look like, and function for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fg7m3/

In this case, absolute positioning, z-index, and opacity are the key elements to make it look like a watermark.

Comment: ++Yes exactly like that!  Also, I like jsfiddle, Thanks!