# asp.net webform programmatically add transparent image

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

I have a maintenance work order web app, and on the work orders I want to check some data and display a transparent watermark over the entire web form under some conditions.  Not just over an image or just in a textbox (like Google keeps saying).

I want to implement something similar to how you can add "Confidential" or "Draft" as a watermark to MS Word documents, only for an entire div in my web form.  Can this be done in CSS?  Can you point me to the properties I should be looking at?

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an image of the watermark you'd like, use css like this to get it on the page:

```
 <style>
 <!--
  body {
   background-image: url(image.gif);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
  }
 //-->
 </style>
```

And you can print the stylesheet only if you want the watermark.

Edit: Or if you don't have an image at hand, you can work it with only text, like this answer: [How can I create a text watermark without an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282040/how-can-i-create-a-text-watermark-without-an-image)

I forked the fiddle out of the linked answer to rotate the text: http://jsfiddle.net/emrRg/1/

Comment: Doing it without an image would be really slick and flexible.  Can I angle the text using CSS?  Or would that need to be done with an image?

Comment: @cederlof- Yep, I found that method too.  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/css/css-cross-browser-text-rotation.html#fbid=ptqwG4NJYqk

Comment: For completeness sake, I set the div to be visible in C# code-behind on certain conditions, and changed its inner html to the text I wanted.  Also, used `-40deg` for watermark rotation, and moved the image down by increasing `top` to 225px.